# Is a proof of this possible?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to prove that $k(x^2+y^2-z^2)+2xzK=k$ given that $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $k$ and $K$ are arbitrary constants?

Answer (score 2):

No, that does not hold true in general. The LHS:

$$k(x^2+y^2-z^2) + 2 x z K= k(x^2+y^2+z^2) - 2 k z^2 + 2 x z K = k - 2 k z^2 +2 x z K$$

Substituting back into the equation:

$$k - 2 k z^2 + 2 x z K = k \quad \iff \quad 2 k z^2 = 2 x z K $$

The latter only holds true if either:

- $\quad z = 0$
- $\quad k z = x K$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = z = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $y = 0$. Then
\begin{align*}
k(x^2 + y^2 - z^2) + 2xzK &= k\\
k(\frac{1}{2} + 0 - \frac{1}{2}) + 2\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cdot\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}K &= k\\
\textrm{so }K &= k,
\end{align*}
which is not true for arbitrary $K$ and $k$.